# TypeScript combine multiple Promises await

Tags: typescript, promise

I have basically a piece of code where I have a variable that consolidates multiple promise awaits and concat them into a single object

```
const traversals = (await traverseSchemas({filename:"my-validation-schema.json"}).concat([
      _.zipObject(
        ["id-1", "id-2"],
        [
          await loadSchema({
            filename: "schema-1.json"
          }),
          await loadSchema({
            filename: "schema-2.json"
          }),
        ]
      ),
    ]);
```

The `traverseSchemas` returns an array object `[{"key1":{object}}, {"key2": {object}}]`

I am exploring if there is a away I can apply await at `traversals` level only to get all the promised fulfilled data or if there is any better way to refactor the code.

Comment: what's the goal of this refactoring? are you trying to make it faster, e.g. parallelize awaits, or just make the code cleaner?

Comment: I am actually more inclined towards cleaner coad and readability

Comment: Please also suggest parallelize awaits just for knowledge purpose

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because no promise depends on the result of another, you can execute all of them simultaneously (in parallel) using `Promise.all`. This only utilizes a single `await` and the `return ...` is a purely synchronous expression combining the awaited values -

```js
async function traversals() {
  const [validation, schema1, schema2] = await Promise.all([
    traverseSchemas({filename:"my-validation-schema.json"}),
    loadSchema({filename: "schema-1.json"}),
    loadSchema({filename: "schema-2.json"}),
  ])

  return [
    ...validation,
    _.zipObject(["id-1", "id-2"], [schema1, schema2])
  ]
}
```

If you have access to top-level `await` or this is already part of another `async` function, you can define `const traversals = ...` instead of using `return` -

```js
const [validation, schema1, schema2] = await Promise.all([
  traverseSchemas({filename:"my-validation-schema.json"}),
  loadSchema({filename: "schema-1.json"}),
  loadSchema({filename: "schema-2.json"}),
])

const traversals = [
  ...validation,
  _.zipObject(["id-1", "id-2"], [schema1, schema2])
]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many options.

Typically plain code is easier to understand. So I would go for something like this:

```
const validationSchemas = await traverseSchemas({ filename:"my-validation-schema.json" })
const schema1 = { "id-1": await loadSchema({ filename: "schema1-json" });
const schema2 = { "id-2": await loadSchema({ filename: "schema2-json" });

const traversals = [ ...fetchedSchemas, schema1, schema2 ];
```

If you want to parallelize awaits, you could prepare them first, then request via [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) and then join together:

```
const tasks = [
    traverseSchemas({ filename:"my-validation-schema.json" }),
    loadSchema({ filename: "schema1-json" }),
    loadSchema({ filename: "schema2-json" })
];

const [validationSchemas, schema1Value, schema2Value] = await Promise.all(tasks);

const traversals = [
    ...validationSchemas,
    { 'id-1': schema1Value },
    { 'id-2': schema2Value }
];
```